# Categorizing dependecy properties in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, dependency-properties, expression-blend

In WPF, Silverlight ect. you had the possibility of categorizing your dependency properties using the [System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx) class.

How do I categorize my DependencyProperties in WinRT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not supported in WinRT, maybe it will be in a later version. But for now it's not a part of the ComponentModel.